# how do i link mssql to android studios?

Tags: sql-server, android-studio

Please bear with, I have a little experience in SQL but otherwise I am a complete newbie when it comes to programming/coding.

I have a database with Microsoft SQL server and I have downloaded Android studios.

In short I want to create a basic app that can have the ability to show data as well as update tables from my database. (app won't be a problem)

The question is, what would be the 'best' way to do to link database to my app? Bearing in mind I am not at a great technical level at the moment

I have been informed that linking to the database to the app directly may pose security risks but other than that I am a bit lost at how to get the information I need to get started...

Any information you can chuck my way will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to download JTDS drivers https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/
If you are not sure about how to set up watch this video as a reference https://youtu.be/UXy_phw5Psg.

To add jar files to your android studio:

Right-click on app > New > Module.
A window will open where you can find jar files when you scroll down.
Select the widget another window will open, find the location of your jar and select.
Finish. That is it you can start creating projects with SQL server after the build is finished.
Now after adding JTDS, you have to Add This Line In Your App Gradle File, *x.x.x* is the version of JTDS that you downloaded

dependencies{
implementation project(':jtds-*x.x.x*')
}

Now we are going to make a java class to connect SQL server and android studio. Remember this class is the heart of your every android project with SQL server.
**Use Imports Correctly.**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionClass {
// Your IP address must be static otherwise this will not work. You //can get your Ip address
//From Network and security in Windows.
String ip = "000.000.000.00";
// This is default if you are using JTDS driver.
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
// Name Of your database.
String db = "MyDB"; 
// Userame and password are required for security. 
so Go to sql server and add username and password for your database.
String un = "username";
String password = "passw0rd";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
.permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
Connection conn = null;
String ConnURL;
try {
Class.forName(classs);
ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
         + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
              + password + ";";
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
  }
 catch (SQLException se) 
{
Log.e("safiya", se.getMessage());
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
} 
catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
}
return conn;
}
}
```

**Strict Mode:**
StrictMode is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing by accident and brings them to your attention so you can fix them.

StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application’s main thread, where UI operations are received and animations take place. Keeping disk and network operations off the main thread makes for much smoother, more responsive applications.

Orignal link to this is guide is https://life-news.blog/2018/09/24/connect-sql-server-with-android-application-jdbc-driver-integration/